# Which program can open a .DJVU file?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, djvu

I received a folder with a bunch of PDF files and one DJVU file.  The PDF's open in PDF Complete but the DJVU does not.  How do I open this type of file?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Internet Explorer 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest [SumatraPDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html).

It opens PDF, XPS, DjVu, CHM, CBZ, CBR and is small and really fast.

Answer (score 5):

Viewers can be found [here](http://djvu.org/resources/).  It's just another (not as widely used) format for [compression](http://djvu.org/resources/whatisdjvu.php) in documents.

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to select both answers but I can't.

Comment: Some feedback: Cuminas doesn't have smooth scrolling. DjVuLibre DjView has a strange way of selecting text where you can't see very well which parts are being selected. WinDjView doesn't have those problems, but it does have an unnecessarily complex UI and a somewhat obtrusive search popup window, unlike sumatraPDF.

Answer (score 1):

You should visit a website suggesting software for various file types like this one:
[File Extension DJVU](http://www.fileextension.org/DJVU)

Here are some examples of Windows software from the site:

- WinDjView
- DjVuLibre DjView
- ACD Systems Canvas 14
- ACD Systems ACDSee 15
- Lizardtech DjVu Solo
- Web browser with LizardTech DjVu Browser plugin

Comment: You shouldn't post [link-only-answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Sites might go offline and hence rendering your answer useless.

Answer (score 1):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com) , The "swiss army knife" for viewing graphic files on Windows, can display DJVU files.

With the [plugin pack](http://www.irfanview.com/plugins.htm) it is also easily possible to save the document as a `PDF` file:

```
File -> Save as... -> PDF
```

[image]